# In ABC find points X,Y,Z such that AXYZ is rhombus

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, geometric-inequalities

Question -

In ABC find points X,Y,Z on AB,BC,CA such that AXYZ is rhombus and  area of AXYZ <= 1/2 AREA OF ABC

My try -

I know it very easy but I am not getting ...I take midpoints of sides and proved that opposite sides are equal by midpoint theorem but not able to prove adjacent sides are also equal ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct bisector $AY$ of $\Delta ABC$.

Let $X\in AB$ such that $XY||AC$ and $Z\in AC$ such that $YZ||AB.$

Thus, $AXYZ$ is a rhombus.

Now, let $XY=k$.

Thus, since $\Delta XBY\sim\Delta ABC,$ in the standard notation we obtain:
$$\frac{k}{b}=\frac{c-k}{c},$$ which gives $$k=\frac{bc}{b+c}.$$
Id est, we need to prove that:
$$\left(\frac{bc}{b+c}\right)^2\sin\alpha\leq\frac{1}{4}bc\sin\alpha$$ or
$$(b-c)^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: 'Construct bisector  of Δ', here you mean the bisector of Angle B right? Thanks!